# How to convert .xls file to .csv or json using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, xls

I'm using `d3.js` to build charts. My dataset is a `.xls` file; but `d3.js` can read `.csv` or `json` files. I tried using `SheetJS` to convert the file to `.csv`, but the browser does not support the `ReadFile` function; this can only be used on a server.

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('data/file.xls');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) {
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
    var headers = {};
    var data = [];
    for(z in worksheet) {
        if(z[0] === '!') continue;
        //parse out the column, row, and value
        var tt = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(z[i])) {
                tt = i;
                break;
            }
        };
        var col = z.substring(0,tt);
        var row = parseInt(z.substring(tt));
        var value = worksheet[z].v;

        //store header names
        if(row == 1 && value) {
            headers[col] = value;
            continue;
        }

        if(!data[row]) data[row]={};
        data[row][headers[col]] = value;
    }
    //drop those first two rows which are empty
    //data.shift();
    //data.shift();
    console.log(data);
});
```

but, the error is:

> Error: Cannot access file data/file.xls

In another answer:

> readFile is only available in server environments.  Browsers have no
>   API for reading arbitrary files given a path, so another strategy must
>   be used.

Do you have any ideas to suggest?

Thank you all

Comment: Does this codepen help at all? https://codepen.io/Aymkdn/pen/aJNPMV

Comment: What is path "data/file.xls" ? Is it on your local machine ? Your browser won't be able to get a file on your computer that easily. Maybe try to host your file on a server and read the file from the URL.

Comment: @Flo yes, "data/file.xls" is in my local machine. Ok, actually I downloaded this file from a site. I try to use the URL for this resource within the function. Thank you.

Comment: If it's on your computer your browser won't be able to access the file directly (that would be a security breach btw). That's why people say it has to be done on server side.

Comment: @Flo Ok, ok, the resource in html is so downloadable: window.location='./Handlers/....' how do i get the URL?